# How to count how many unique records with multiple records in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have customer table as the following:

```
CustomerID, ReferenceID    
1   ,101    
2   ,101    
3   ,101    
4   ,102    
5   ,102    
6   ,103
```

I want to count how many ReferenceID has multiple customerID and I write the following query:

```
SELECT CustomerID,  ReferenceID, Count(1)
FROM   Customer
group by CustomerID,    ReferenceID    
having Count(1) >1
```

I should get number 2 because of 2 ReferenceID have multiple customerID  , but I do not get any number

Comment: you need to remove the `CustomerID` from both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ReferenceIdCount INT

SELECT @ReferenceIdCount = COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          ReferenceId
          ,COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) as ReferenceCount
       FROM
          @Table
       GROUP BY
          ReferenceId
       HAVING
          COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) > 1
    ) t
```

First you have to find the ReferenceId's that have multiple CustomerIds then next you have to count them.  So you can do this many ways but the nested select is an easy way to show you.

Comment: glad to here it, please accept the answer if it works for you.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Can I set this number as variable ?

Comment: sure I have updated the answer to reflect your new requirement

Answer (score 0):

Can I set this number as variable ?

Declare @RFCount

set @RFCount = (

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          ReferenceId
          ,COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) as ReferenceCount
       FROM
          @Table
       GROUP BY
          ReferenceId
       HAVING
          COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) > 1
    ) t)

print @FCount

I get error message for the above statement